# Why does ^metadata 'symbol not work?

Tags: clojure, metadata, read-eval-print-loop

The [documentation on metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata) claims that `^{:hi 10} 'x` is equivalent to `(with-meta 'x {:hi 10})`, but I can't see that.

Evaluating the following on a repl,

```
(binding [*print-meta* true]
  (prn ^{:hi 10} 'x)
  (prn (with-meta 'x {:hi 10})))
```

prints the following, which shows that the first case doesn't get the metadata attached.

```
x
^{:hi 10} x
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` is a [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) which attaches metadata to the form that follows it. However, `'x` is not a form to which metadata can be applied; it expands to `(quote x)` via the `'` reader macro. When you type `^{:hi 10} 'x`, the metadata gets attached to the un-evaluated `(quote x)` form and not the bare symbol `x`:

```
user> (set! *print-meta* true)
user> (prn (read-string "'x"))
(quote x)
user> (prn (read-string "^{:hi 10} 'x"))
^{:hi 10} (quote x)
```

However, evaluating a form with metadata does not carry the metadata through to the result:

```
 user> (prn (eval (read-string "^{:hi 10} 'x")))
 x
```

You can attach metadata to a quoted symbol by placing the `^` *after* the `'`, as in:

```
user> (prn (read-string "'^{:hi 10} x"))
(quote ^{:hi 10} x)
user> (prn '^{:hi 10} x)
^{:hi 10} x
```